# For Local Notification, how to show a "Alert" when the app is running in the foreground?

Tags: ios, ios5

I need the app gives an alert when it's running in foreground

I test it in my device , when it's in background , the alert shows ; But when app comes in foreground , no alert shows , does this happen by default ?

I've searched some questions , someone says that I can mimic an alert using "UIAlertView"...

Is there any other proper way to do this ?

Comment: Can you show us how you are setting up your Local Notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your app is foreground, you have to handle the notification. The system won't pop up an alert for you, you have to catch the notification in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` and deal with it yourself.

If you want an alert, then in that method you should summon a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: <b>if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
  // show an alert view here
}</b>

Answer (score 1):

I'll do like this:

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {
  // show an alert view
}
else {
  // your local notification configuration
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kjuly is right with the above, but you should also check for UIApplicationStateInactive. It may be easier just to check if

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState != UIApplicationStateActive